# Using Horner's method to find P(x) and P'(x)

Tags: python, numerical-analysis

My textbook gives the pseudo code for Horner's method as follows:

```
P(x) = a_n x n + a_n−1 x n−1 + ··· + a_1 x + a_0 = (x−x0)Q(x) + b0

INPUT degree n; coefficients a_0 , a_1 , . . . , a_n ; x0 .
OUTPUT y = P(x 0 ); z = P (x 0 ).
Step 1 Set y = a_n ; (Compute b n for P.)
           z = a_n . (Compute b n−1 for Q.)
Step 2 For j = n − 1, n − 2, . . . , 1
           set y = x0 * y + a_j ; (Compute b_j for P.)
                   z = x0 * z + y. (Compute b_j−1 for Q.)
Step 3 Set y = x0 + y + a_0 .
Step 4 OUTPUT (y, z);
       STOP.
```

Now the issue I have here is that the subscript in the pseudo code does not seem to match the subscripts in the formula

I did a python implementation, but the the answers I got seemed wrong, so I changed it slightly

```
def horner(x0, *a):
    '''
        Horner's method is an algorithm to calculate a polynomial at
        f(x0) and f'(x0)

        x0 - The value to avaluate
        a - An array of the coefficients

        The degree is the polynomial is set equal to the number of coefficients
    '''
    n = len(a)

    y = a[0]
    z = a[0]
    for j in range(1, n):
        y = x0 * y + a[j]
        z = x0 * z + y

    y = x0 * y + a[-1]

    print('P(x0) =', y)
    print('P\'(x0) =', z)
```

It works pretty well, but I need someone with more experience in this regard to give it a once over.

As a very basic test I took the polynomial 2x^4 with a value of -2 for x.

To use it in the method I call it as such

```
horner(-2, 2, 0, 0 ,0)
```

The output does indeed look correct for this very simple problem. Since f(x) = 2x^4 then f(-2) = -32, but this is where my implementation gives a different result my answer is positive

Comment: Can you provide the example input and the desired output?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method#Python_implementation your input and expected output would help

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham, I did read the wiki page and had a look at their algorithm. The slight difference is that I am trying to solve the derivative at the same time

Comment: Positive answer for that is [correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*x%5E4%2C+x%3D-2)

Comment: according to the algorithm you start at the end and reverse which will give different results if you have any non zero value

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and I am adding the answer here since it may prove useful to someone in the future

Firstly there is a but in the algorithm, the loop must go up to n-1

```
def horner(x0, *a):
    '''
        Horner's method is an algorithm to calculate a polynomial at
        f(x0) and f'(x0)

        x0 - The value to avaluate
        a - An array of the coefficients

        The degree is the polynomial is set equal to the number of coefficients
    '''
    n = len(a)

    y = a[0]
    z = a[0]
    for j in range(1, n - 1):
        y = x0 * y + a[j]
        z = x0 * z + y

    y = x0 * y + a[-1]

    print('P(x0) =', y)
    print('P\'(x0) =', z)
```

Second, and this was my biggest mistake, I am not passing enough coefficients to the method

This will calculate 2x^3

```
horner(-2, 2, 0, 0, 0)
```

I actually had to call

```
horner(-2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: `y = 0 z = 0 for j in a[:-1]` will do the exact same thing